# Django - beginner tips for test writing?

Tags: python, django, selenium, testing, functional-programming

I am Django beginner and I need to learn how to write functional and unit tests. I am going to start with documentation, but maybe someone knows good tutorials or has some good tips to share? Should I use "Selenium" for functional tests or is it considered a bad practise?

Also I am wondering what percentage of the code should I cover with tests?

Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: You should aim for 100% coverage of your own code. Aiming for less is like saying: "well, I don't care whether this part works or not." Selenium has its use (that's why it exists) but should be used in the right context, not for everything. It really is too broad to give a straight answer.

Answer (score 1):

As for resources, right after you finish with the docs go straight for this book, it'll cover nearly everything about writing tests in django, from simple to complex tests:

http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/

Now for code coverage, one basic thing you'll learn in the book above is to test everything, quoting from page 1 of the book:

> **Obey the Testing Goat! Do nothing until you have a test**

---

One great tool you will find most useful while testing coverage of your tests is [coverage.py](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/), it will tell you how much of your code is covered by your tests, here's what the django docs say about it:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/advanced/#integration-with-coverage-py

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of tips:

Don't use Django fixtures in your tests. Use factories instead (factory_boy for example). With factories your functional tests are independent, faster and easier to read/understand.

For your functional tests: if you use a lot of javascript, go with Selenium. If you don't, go with WebTest.

Read a lot about it; google: TDD, WebTest Django, fast tests Django, mock, unit VS functional tests, BDD, etc.